# Mocking authentication in Spring: List of providers throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, mockito

I'm trying to mock authentication in Java for an authentication. This is my test class for mocking the code:

```java
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(this.controller).build();

    final List<AuthenticationProvider> providers = mock(ArrayList.class);
    final AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider provider = mock(
            AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.class);
    when(provider.supports(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(false);
    when(providers.size()).thenReturn(1);
    session = new MockHttpSession();
    when(providers.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(provider);
    when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(session);
    when(request.getSession(false)).thenReturn(session);
    when(providers.iterator()).thenReturn(new Iterator<AuthenticationProvider>() {
        private int currentIndex = 0;

        @Override
        public AuthenticationProvider next() {

            return providers.get(currentIndex++);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return currentIndex < providers.size() && providers.get(currentIndex) != null;
        }
    });
    SingleProviderAuthenticationManager manager = new SingleProviderAuthenticationManager(providers);
    Map<String, AuthenticationManager> map = new HashMap<String, AuthenticationManager>();
    map.put("db", manager);

    filter.setAuthenticationManagerMap(map);
    when(request.getMethod()).thenReturn("POST");
    when(request.getParameter("username")).thenReturn("admin");
    when(request.getParameter("password")).thenReturn("admin");

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    User user = new User();
    user.setSourceSystem("db");
    users.add(user);
    when(userService.getUserReferenceByUsername("admin")).thenReturn(users);
    auth = filter.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
```

Now, on the line where I put the manager in the `map.put()` method, when I put "db" it actually gives the provider manager as `null` and I get the `NullPointerException` in the `ProviderManager`.

```java
    for (AuthenticationProvider provider : getProviders()) {
        if (!provider.supports(toTest)) {
            continue;
        }
```

Even though I've tested the same thing in my main code with the providers I pass its still showing a `NullPointerException`. And if I put "ldap" instead it gives me a `NullPointerException` in the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` here:
(last line where the return happens)

```java
        password = "";
    }

    username = username.trim();

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

    // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
    setDetails(request, authRequest);

    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
}
```

I am stuck here, both these things when I pass them are not at all `null`. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mock ArrayList instead create new array list and send it to actual class like below :

```
    final List<AuthenticationProvider> providers = new ArrayList<>();
    providers.add("AuthenticationProvider object values");
```

// when(providers.size()).thenReturn(1); -- no need of doing this stuff if you create direct arraylist object.

PS- If you are working with collections, do prefer creating new objects and send that object to actual class instead of mocking and sending, that is the best practice.

Hope it's useful.